# How is the 'this' attribute used in Fable?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

im using Fable as part of building a website. I was looking at the documentation in an attempt to create a slider, and came across this :

```
div [ ]
    [ Slider.slider [ Slider.OnChange this.onSlide ]
      div [ ]
        [ str (string this.state.Ratio) ] ]
```

Although using said code introduced the following error:

`The value, namespace, type or module 'this' is not defined`

I was just wondering whether this was an error with the documentation or perhaps there was a new approach to self referring objects

Im using the following packages :

```
open Fable.React
open Fable.React.Props
open Fulma
open Fulma.Extensions.Wikiki
```

Additionally, nothing to be found on the source file:
https://github.com/Fulma/Fulma/blob/master/src/Fulma.Extensions.Wikiki.Slider/Slider.fs

thanks :) !

Comment: `this` is not a thing in F# and does not have a special meaning like in C#. If you see `this` used in a piece of code, it's just an identifier like any other, and it must be defined somewhere above, either as a function parameter, or as a `let`-binding or in some other way. You did not provide a link to whence you got that piece of code, so I can't point you whither `this` is defined.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Hello, thanks for the response, I got the code from the very last item in [this page](https://fulma.github.io/Fulma/#fulma-extensions/slider) , (Click 'view code'). There seems to be no mention of `this`  unless im missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not a thing in F# and does not have a special meaning like in C#. If you see `this` used in a piece of code, it's just an identifier like any other, and it must be defined somewhere above, either as a function parameter, or as a let-binding, or in some other way.

In your particular case, the code in question comes from [this file](https://github.com/Fulma/Fulma/blob/3b844cfc879162dba1d02e150bdf2a05dfb7bdfb/docs/src/FulmaExtensions/Slider.fs#L67-L71), and it is on line 67 that `this` is defined:

```ml
             right here
                  |
                vvvv
67:    override this.render () =
68:        div [ ]
69:            [ Slider.slider [ Slider.OnChange this.onSlide ]
70:              div [ ]
71:                [ str (string this.state.Ratio) ] ]
```

Here `render` is an instance method of the surrounding `SliderDemo` class, and this particular syntax binds the identifier to the instance of the class.

---

But, just to reiterate, it doesn't have to be `this`, that's just a convention. It could just as well have been any other valid identifier, for example:

```ml
    override foo.render () =
        div [ ]
            [ Slider.slider [ Slider.OnChange foo.onSlide ]
              div [ ]
                [ str (string foo.state.Ratio) ] ]
```

Using `this` is kind of a semi-accepted practice, because that particular word is also used as a keyword in other languages, and with the same meaning. Many people use `self` instead.

Comment: Id have never found that out without your help, it'll also help when looking up other errors in the future. Thanks so much for the response, makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Glad I could help